# How do I filter items using data-filter="true" within a nested list (all levels) in jquery mobile (Search filter bar)

Tags: jquery, list, mobile, nested

I have a nested list in jquery mobile. I can search through every single nesting level by setting the attributes

```
data-role="listview" data-filter="true"
```

on every  that is nested. But how can I search through the entire list from top-level?

I already tried adding

```
data-filtertext=""
```

attributes to all  in the nested list... no success :(

I want to use "Search filter bar" but I do not know how to apply it to the entire list!

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('[data-filter="true"]').each(function(){
   alert($(this).text())
})
```

Comment: You are 100% right ;)
I did not ask properly.. I want to know how to apply a filter through "Search filter bar"